# How to add UIImage and UILabel if UITableView has no data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiimage

I've looked into many answers but either it's only `UILabel` or `UIImage` not both. So after trying to implement it I finally found that we cannot do two `tableView.backgroundView`. Here is what I've done so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        let noDataLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))

let image = UIImage(named: "noData")
let noDataImage = UIImageView(image: image)

noDataImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20)

if allData.count == 0 {

noDataLabel.isHidden = false
noDataImage.isHidden = false

noDataLabel.text          = "No data added. Add new entry \nby pressing the add icon on top right."
noDataLabel.textColor     = UIColor.black
noDataLabel.numberOfLines = 3
noDataLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
noDataLabel.textAlignment = .center

 //what to do from here           
            tableView.backgroundView  = noDataImage
            tableView.backgroundView  = noDataLabel

//end
                tableView.separatorStyle  = .none
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                noDataLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                noDataLabel.isHidden = true
                noDataImage.isHidden = true
                tableView.backgroundView  = nil
                return allData.count
            }
```

I want to show an image and below that image I want to show a `UILabel`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would put the tableView above your "No Data" view and make the tableViews background transparent.

Comment: You mean on the UIView I should add the image and label and if there is count zero then I should just make the background of table transparent?

Comment: create a View than Asign to Background View , this has been already answered by @arpit below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `view` with `subviews` your `image` and `label`

```
var backgroundView =UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, your_width, your_height))
backgroundView.addSubview(noDataImage)
backgroundView.addSubview(noDataLabel)

 tableView.backgroundView=backgroundView;
```

Note: Adjust the frame of `noDataImage` and `noDataLabel` as per your use.

Answer (score 0):

```
backgroundView Property
```

The background view of the table view.

Declaration

Swift

var backgroundView: UIView?

Objective-C

@property(nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UIView *backgroundView

Discussion

A table view’s background view is automatically resized to match the size of the table view. This view is placed as a subview of the table view behind all cells, header views, and footer views.

You must set this property to nil to set the background color of the table view.